# Adding two kebab case css class in an element in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './stylesheet.moudle.css'

<div className={styles['first-style'] styles['second-style']}>
some content
</div>
```

How do I add `styles['second-style']` into the className? I tried comma and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
<div className={`${styles['first-style']} ${styles['second-style']}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using classnames npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

You can do more complex things with this in a clean way.

```
import classNames from 'classNames'

const condition = true;

<div className={
  classNames(
     styles.first-style,
     styles.second-style,
     {'styles.some-other-conditional-classname': condition})}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx).

```
const Toolbar = ({
  className,
  ...rest
}) => {
    <Component
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
      {...rest}
    >
    ...
}
```